# How to return 2 elements after using .split()

Tags: jquery

Need to pull elements out of the URL of the current page the user is on, for example:
http://www.example.com/1/2/3

I need to return: 2,3

So I'm using:
$(location).attr('href').split('/')

and if I add [5] or [6] I can isolate those elements 2 and 3 individually, but how can I combine them, and then if I successfully combine them, how can I connect them with by a comma with no spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: `str.split('/').slice(4, 6).join(',')` [:)](http://jsfiddle.net/e7e9dogt/)

Comment: That's great, I see how that works by popping off the 5th and 6th elements, but if my URL is actually http://www.example.com/1/2/3/4 - How could I use this same method to return 2,3 without returning 2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the string "2,3" you can do the following:

```
var parts = $(location).attr('href').split('/');
return parts[5] + ',' + parts[6];
```

It would be wise to check to see that `parts.length` contains a `parts[6]` prior to trying to access it to prevent errors.